# read and write scsi devices file from linux , like sdb,sdc

Tags: c, linux, usb, scsi

I want to write my own tag on the device file (scsi file sdb, sdc...) on Linux.

I use linux C `open()`, `read()`, `write()` functions on `/dev/sdb` file, write my key  in this file. But when usb disk device Unplug from computer and plug again, in `/dev/sdb`'s key, sometimes it's gone, or is unstable.

I don't know why.

```
char readBuf[512] = { 0 }; 
char key[12] = "h%27dcd*()jd"; 
int fd = open("/dev/sdb",O_RDWR); 
lseek(fd,1024,SEEK_SET); 
read(fd,readBuf,512); 
for(int i=0; i<sizeof key; ++i) 
{ 
    readBuf[i] = ~key[i]; 
} 
lseek(fd,1024,SEEK_SET); 
write(fd,readBuf,512);
//In order to mark the Usb disk bear fruit...
```

Comment: You should show us exactly what you did and exactly what happened. Formula: 1) What did you do? 2) What did you expect to happen? 3) What actually happened?

Comment: sorry..........
i did
Probably so...
char readBuf[512] = { 0 };
char key[12] = "h%27dcd*()jd";
int fd = open("/dev/sdb",O_RDWR);

lseek(fd,1024,SEEK_SET);

read(fd,readBuf,512);
for(int i=0; i<sizeof key;  ++i)
{
    readBuf[i] = ~key[i]; 
}
 
lseek(fd,1024,SEEK_SET);
write(fd,readBuf,512);//In order to mark the Usb disk

bear fruit...
read key when usb disk device Unplug from computer and plug again this key disappear

Comment: You should put it in the question so it's easier to read. Also show how you checked whether the key was still there.

Comment: Also did you try running `sync` before unplugging the USB drive?

Answer (score 0):

*for setting a fixed mount point:*

you can assign a static mount point (like `/dev/sdb`) for USB devices using `udev` rules and a `symlink`. you can identify the device in the udev rule by i.e. *vendor id* and *product id*,...

`ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", SYMLINK+="my_device"`

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66901/how-to-bind-usb-device-under-a-static-name

*for writing bit-wise to specific memory location on the stick:*

to write data bytewise to arbitrary blocks on a block device use tools like `dd` ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix) ). file io tools like `read()`, `write()` can not be used for writing bytewise WITHOUT using a file...

Comment: (idVendor,idProduct) these I all get,  I just want to write something  in /dev/sdb  file  ,But is unstable  when i use open(), read(), write() functions,like Data missed.........

Comment: if you have a second device that is USB mass storage connect this and check if it is also on this device. maybe this is a hardware error (flash chips broken, or USB port physical connection,...). you can use `libusb` for this see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772152/read-write-on-a-pen-drive-using-libusb-libusb-bulk-transfer normally the kernel module (`usb_storage`) is responsible for this

Comment: your mean is my way(open,read(),write()) is no wrong, 
maybe this is a hardware error ?   I always thought (open(),read(),write) is wrong...

Comment: the kernel module (driver) `usb_storage` enables the os to see the usb device as part of its file system (`/dev/sdbx`) by mounting it. so you should be able to use standard file system operations like `open()`, `read()`, `write()`,... so if you want to write something with file io commands you have to create a file on the drive you can not write `h%27dcd*()jd` anywhere on the usb stick you want because there is an internal structuring of the memory in block devices (block size, file system table,...)

Comment: see  http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/28532570/how-do-i-write-directly-to-a-usb-drive-with-over-4gb-data to write data bytewise to arbitrary blocks on the device use tools like `dd` ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix) )